# Using twitter bootstrap with existing application

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm migrating my existing ASP.NET application to ASP.NET MVC. I've planned to use twitter bootstrap library at the front end for admin module. The important thing is I want to retain the styles used in the existing application (as it is) which is quite different from bootstrap style. Is it good to use twitter bootstrap in this case? How I can customize twitter bootstrap to fit to my existing website theme?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter bootstrap having rich collection of tools for building web sites. I don't know how much it suitable for asp.net. Better you can try for some sample application by using twitter bootstrap css. Could you check in such a way that make a button using asp then you apply the twitter bootstrap css class in to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick and choose which components and/or styles you want (and don't want) [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/).

Answer (score 0):

This is not very good idea to customize twitter bootstrap, cause it's easy to get lost in the source code of bootstrap. So if you want to save current theme, it would be better continue to use custom styles for your app. 
But bootstrap is very useful thing. Think about using bootstrap instead your current styles.